# Authorize only Authorizing Transaction instead of Authorizing & Capturing

Tags: authorize.net

> On a fresh 2.3.3 install,

I am having an issue where despite setting "Authorize & Capture" under the Authorize Payment method (not Directpost), only the "Authorize" step is being executed; no invoice is being created and so we have to capture funds by hand. Obviously with a large store, this is not sustainable.

Indeed, when looking at the request in our payment log, we see `authOnlyTransaction` as our `transactionType`.

**Is this a known bug in 2.3.3 or is there something about the products or our configuration that appears to be incorrect?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a relatively simple problem although impossible (to my knowledge) to see from a site utilizing single site mode.

I had two records in my `core_config` table and even though the default was set to `authorize_capture` the website record was not, despite updating.  Upon updating this record and clearing cache, authorize and capture works as expected.

[image]